# The Universal enveloping algebra of a finite dimensional Lie algebra is Noetherian.

Tags: lie-algebras

If $\mathfrak{g}$ is a finite-dimensional Lie algebra, then it is very known that the Universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g})$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Noetherian ring.
What is the simplest way to show this fact?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a nice treatment in [this](http://books.google.ca/books?id=c3fWk8LoSvgC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) book. In particular, the associated graded ring $\operatorname{gr}U(\mathfrak g)$ is shown to be a finitely generated commutative $k$-algebra, generated by at most $\dim_k\mathfrak g$ elements over $k.$ It is a basic fact that such rings are noetherian, so this implies that $U(\mathfrak g)$ is itself noetherian.